# Load EditorTemplate with new model on ajax call - MVC project

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to make an ajax call which will load a new model and reload my editorTemplates based on the current loaded model.

Right now I have create an HotelModel which look like this:

```
public class HotelsModel
{
    public List<HotelsReservationModel> HotelsReservation { get; set; }
    public bool SkipButton { get; set; }
}

public class HotelsReservationModel
{

    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckOut { get; set; }
    public List<Hotel> Hotels { get; set; }

}

public class Hotel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have created some EditorTemplates: **HotelsReservationModel.cshtml & Hotel.cshtml**

Right now, I have the following order:

1. Index.cshtml (calling HotelsModel)
2. HotelsReservationModel.cshtml (calling HotelsReservationModel)
3. Hotel.cshtml (calling Hotel)

I'm trying to pass in a new Hotel (model), so when a user click on search, an ajax call will happen and some knew hotels should appear.

**My ajax code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    var res = {
        loader: $("<div />", { class: "loader" }),
    };

    $('#search').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "@Url.Action("Find", "Hotel")",
            datatype: "html",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#group-panel-ajax").append(res.loader);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#group-panel-ajax").find(res.loader).remove();
                $('#group-panel-ajax').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

**Code from HotelsReservationModel.cshtml**

```
<div class="group-panel" id="group-panel-ajax">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Hotels)
</div>
```

**ActionResult Find method**

```
public ActionResult Find()
    {
        Hotel model = new Hotel()
        {
            Name = "Cromwell Hotel ",
            Rating = 5,

        };

        return PartialView("Hotel", model);

    }
```

Can any see what I am doing wrong?

If i run "Return PartialView("Index", model) something is loaded.. what then the whole page with the model is loaded inside the div. What i want is to just load the "Hotel" --> Hotel.cshtml with the new model.

Comment: Could you clarify what's not working ? Does your ajax call reach your server method ? Is there any data returned in your success callback ?

Comment: When i try load the "Index" page it works.. but i want it to load the Hotel page inside the EditorTemplate folder.

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice solution for my problem.

What did the trick is to wrap the data in Jquery and using the method find and point in on the div it should recreate.

First code:

```
$('#group-panel-ajax').html(data);
```

Final code:

```
 $('#group-panel-ajax').html($(data).find("#group-panel-ajax"));
```